# Custom Menu Link Descriptions

Tags: wordpress, menu, hyperlink

I am building a custom WordPress theme and need to add descriptions to my custom menu links. According to WordPress, there is a way to do this:

"The description will be displayed in the menu if the current theme supports it."

Does anyone know how to support this?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress' documentation on this is misleading. It actually took me quite some time to find out how to do this myself. As long as your theme supports menus (meaning, you've [Registered a Custom Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) within functions.php or elsewhere), you can add Link Descriptions and other useful information by default.

In order to SEE these options, go to Appearance->Menus and click on Screen Options (up in the top right-hand corner of the screen). You will be able to enable the options you like under "Show advanced menu properties".

Comment: "This is not working" doesn't tell me anything. Do you see the options as I've described? How are you trying to access your descriptions? Seeing as how you haven't given any code samples to work with, there is no feasible way for me - or anybody else - to provide a code solution. Your best bet is to [Do Some Research Yourself](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu) and open a new question when you can provide a clearer description of what the actual problem is.